# Text overfull in listing

Tags: listings, overfull

I'm encountering an overfull hbox issue with my LaTeX listings, and I need some assistance in resolving it. Here's a brief overview of my problem:

Issue: When I include code listings in my LaTeX document, the text exceeds the page width, causing overfull hbox warnings.

Attempted Solution: I tried adjusting the linewidth parameter in the lstlisting environment, but it only changed the width of the listing frame, not the width of the text within it.

Desired Outcome: I want to constrain the text within a certain width (e.g., 15cm) without affecting the frame of the listing. Essentially, I want the listing to display the code within a specific width, preventing it from going beyond the page boundaries.

Sample Code:

```
\lstnewenvironment{icetorque}[1][] 
{\lstset{frame=shadowbox,escapechar=`,linewidth=15cm, #1}}
{}
```

The output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Try with the `breaklines=true` option.

Comment: If this does not help, please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: You need to add a MWE including the documentclass and needed packages to reproduce your issue. There are different packages that provide listing environments, and without a MWE it could be difficult or bothersome to try to reproduce your issue. That being said, have you tried the option `breaklines=true`?

Comment: In you'd probably also want `breakatwhitespace=true` in addition to `breaklines=true`